# How to emit event to default layout in nuxt composition api?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to emit a event from a index component to default layout.

I know if I want to emit event to default layout, I can use $nuxt.$emit, but my project is using nuxt composition api.
In this situation, is it still can emit event to default layout?

in child component, I will use this function.

```
const updateList = () => {
  emit('update');
}
```

but layout can't get this update event.

I want to use `$nuxt.$emit` in composition api component.

How to use `$nuxt.$emit` in composition api component?

Answer (score 1):

Composition API setup function takes two parameters: `setup(props, context)`. Context contains emit function you are looking for.

You either need to call it as `context.emit('someEvenet')` or use destructuring in setup as `setup(props, { emit })` and use it like you would conventionally

Comment: It's about component emit. == this.$emit.
How to use $nuxt.$emit?